# spark sql: count occurrences with different predicates

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say I've got data like this

```
| department | user  | purchases |
|:-----------|------:|:---------:|
| sport      | user1 |     1     |
| video      | user1 |     7     |
| audio      | user2 |     5     |
| book       | user2 |     3     |
| sport      | user2 |     8     |
```

and so on. I need bucketing on purchases count inside each category like this:

```
| department | users5  | users7  |  users16 |
|:-----------|--------:|:-------:|:--------:|
| sport      | 10      |   5     |     3    |
| video      | 7       |   6     |     4    |
| audio      | 3       |   1     |     0    |
| book       | 5       |   1     |     0    |
```

users5 - count of users having <= 5 purchases in that department

users7 - count of users having 5 to 7 purchases in that department

users16 - count of users having 7 to 16 purchases in that department

I can achieve the goal by following: (spark sql pseudocode)

```
val users5 = df.filter("purchases" < 5).groupby("category").agg(count("user"))
val users7 = df.filter("purchases" >= 5 AND "purchases" < 7).groupby("category").agg(count("user"))
val users16 = df.filter("purchases" >= 7 AND "purchases" < 16).groupby("category").agg(count("user"))
users5.join(users7, Seq("category"), "outer").join(users16, Seq("category"), "outer")
```

My question is there any more general clear approach to do same job?
I'm using apache spark 2.3

Comment: are you okay with a sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option with a SQL query.

```
val res=spark.sql("""
                  select category
                        ,count(case when purchases<=5 then user end) as users5
                        ,count(case when purchases>5 and purchases<7 then user end) as users7
                        ,count(case when purchases>=7 and purchases<16 then user end) as users16
                  from df
                  group by category
                  """
                 )
```

Comment: Totally makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want in api way then following is the solution

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("category").agg(sum(when(col("purchases") < 5, 1).otherwise(0)).as("users5"),
  sum(when(col("purchases") >= 5 && col("purchases") < 7, 1).otherwise(0)).as("users7"),
  sum(when(col("purchases") >= 7 && col("purchases") < 16, 1).otherwise(0)).as("users16"))
  .show(false)
```